# SQL Anywhere Error - 210: User 'another user' has the row in 'tablexyz' locked

Tags: jdbc, sap-iq

I have multiple Java process which launches serially one by one. This process does job of loading data into tablexyz and then tablefinal. After first process finishes its job I get the following error:

> SQL Anywhere Error - 210: User 'another user' has the row in 'tablexyz' locked.

It goes like this:

Process 1:
Creates table tablexyz and loads data into it does some processing and then finally copies data into tablefinal. I commit transaction here after all steps.

Process 2:
Drops/Empties table tablexyz if it is there and then again creates table tablexyz and loads data into it does some processing and then finally copies data into tablefinal. I commit transaction here after all steps.

My app fails at the process 2 and it gives tablexyz locked. I don't understand both process uses same database user myuser then why second process is not able to delete tablexyz created by first process. I am new to Sybase IQ.

Comment: Are you using IQ or Anywhere?

Comment: Hi Database is Sybase iq and jdbc driver is Anywhere

Comment: Do you have RLV enabled on IQ database?

Comment: I am sorry what is RLV I am new to Sybase iq

Answer (score 0):

the reason for this error is that maybe an user works with this "already existing" view/table.

Just look with sp_iqlock.

If it's locked a dba/admin/creator has to unlock it or drop the user which is locking the table.

Answer (score 0):

One possible cause for that error is Sybase IQ option making use of an apparent existing [Simplex](https://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc01840.1604/doc/html/dhe1338473989032.html) database mode.

The error in the question is refered in the [documentation](https://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.sqlanywhere.12.0.0/saerrors/errm210.html) as being caused by a option named blocking being OFF.

`set temporary option blocking = 'Off';`

*Note: The blocking option can be set either at the connection or PUBLIC level.*

Hoping this still helpfull to someone.

Possible fix by changing setting (note that this might have some performance impact)

`set option blocking = 'On';`